# PHP split list items into 2 columns

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am running a Wordpress site, that uses individual ACF fields to store bullet point text.

```
<?php if( get_field('bullet_points') ): ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <p class="big"><?php the_field('bullet_point_text'); ?></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-3">
                        <ul>
                            <?php while( has_sub_field('bullet_points') ): ?>
                            <?php $post_counter++; ?>
                            <li><?php the_sub_field('individual_bullet_point'); ?></li>
                                <?php
                                    if ( 0 == $post_counter % 5 ) {
                                    echo '</ul></div><div class="col-3"><ul>';
                                    }
                                ?>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

The above code takes the fields (bullet_points) and outputs them in multiple columns every 5 points - I hardcoded this to make sure the code works. How would I get it to output these into 2 (as evenly) spaced lists?

So, if I have 6 points, I want 3 in the first DIV and 3 in the second DIV. Similarly if I have 7 points, I want 3 in the first DIV and 4 in the second DIV.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why wouldn't it be 3 in the first column, 3 in the second, and 1 in the third?

Comment: I only need a max of 2 columns - so as the list is dynamic it needs to split it evenly

Comment: you'd need to get a count of the list items first, so you know where to "break" the list. then it's as simple as `first col count = ceil(number of items / 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work...

```
<?php $count_bullets = count(get_sub_field('bullet_points')); ?>
<?php $col_items = ceil( $count_bullets / 2 ); ?>
<?php while( has_sub_field('bullet_points') ): ?>
<?php $post_counter++; ?>
<li><?php the_sub_field('individual_bullet_point'); ?></li>
    <?php
        if ( 0 == $post_counter % $col_items ) {
        echo '</ul></div><div class="col-3"><ul>';
        }
    ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Pretty close - modified <?php $count_bullets = count(get_sub_field('bullet_points')); ?> to <?php $count_bullets = count(get_field('bullet_points')); ?> and that did the trick.